# Can I change registry permission through cmd

Tags: command-line, cmd, registry

Is there any way to change the registry permission through cmd directly. I am developing an application and want registry access. I don't want the user to know about the back end process. And the user can't get administrator rights every time. So once the application run as administrator, the permission should be changed.

Answer (score 1):

I use [PsExec](http://ss64.com/nt/psexec.html) and run my registry commands via a reg file. You can impersonate the user if they are a local admin or as a user that has remote registry access.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what exactly you're trying to do, the `REG` [command allows command-line registry manipulation](http://ss64.com/nt/reg.html), including adding, exporting, querying or importing entries.